# Laravel, create local scope in another class

Tags: laravel, model, scope

I have a model Tasks; i want to create some local scope; we can create it with:

```
public function scopeIstasked($query){
  return $query;
}
```

but i want to create it on another file as service cause maybe i can ended with so much scope that my model is not readable anymore

so i create TaskScopeService.php

```
class TaskScopeService {
    public function showConcerned($query){
        $query = $query->whereHas('organisations.organisateur', function($query){
            $query->where('customers.id', Auth::id());
        });

        return $query;
    }

    public function showToFromAll($query){
        $query = $query->where(function($query){
            $query->where('porter', 'close')->whereHas('customer', function($query){
                $query->isfriend();
            })->whereDoesntHave('group');
        });

        return $query;
    }
}
```

i want to merge these function into my model that can be used as scope behavior; I just use the simple way that call the class inside my model constructor and use them inside scope function but i end with so much scope function in my model as the situation i didn't want

Comment: that's what traits are for https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: use trait instead of class, and use that in your model.

Comment: i want to use my function to behave like local scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the methods inside a trait

```
trait TaskScopeService {
    public function scopeConcerned($query){
        $query = $query->whereHas('organisations.organisateur', function($query){
            $query->where('customers.id', Auth::id());
        });

        return $query;
    }

    public function scopeToFromAll($query){
        $query = $query->where(function($query){
            $query->where('porter', 'close')->whereHas('customer', function($query){
                $query->isfriend();
            })->whereDoesntHave('group');
        });

        return $query;
    }
}
```

and then use it in the class Task

```
class Task extends Model 
{
    use TaskScopeService;
//...
}
```

to use the a scope function which name start with `scope` do:

```php
Task::concerned()->get();
//or combine them
Task::toFromAll()->concerned()->get();
```

**Edit**

To make the `scopeConcerned()` independent from your session (and not use Auth::id() inside it) declare it with a parameter.

```
public function scopeConcerned($query, $customerId){
    $query = $query->whereHas('organisations.organisateur', function($query) use($customerId) {
        $query->where('customers.id', $customerId);
    });

    return $query;
}
```

and use it like this

```
Task::concerned(Auth::id())->get();
```

Comment: so how can i call the scope in my query on my controller? is just Modell::showConcerned() ? or something else?

Comment: i want to use my function to behave like local scope

Comment: @MichelGisenaël added an example, you need to rename the function so they start with `scope` more details here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes

Comment: @MichelGisenaël just for info, your scope `concerned` is dependent on the session, you should change it and use it with a parameter.

Comment: i tried it but even if i didn't call any scope, it always return error 500 without message, but if i add public function index inside the trait, no more error but  i can't use the scope too

Comment: does your class Task implements an interface ? what has the 500 error to do with a trait ?

Comment: nope, i do just like you example; i have an api which use the model, so when i use the trait, my api return error even if i didn't call the scope

Comment: @MichelGisenaël and what is the error you are getting ? that will help move this discussion foreward.

Comment: There is no error message, there is the problem, it's just return status code 500

Comment: @MichelGisenaël check the laravel log and if nothing is there, check your sever error log (apache or nginx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mixins

```
namespace App\Mixins;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class BuilderMixins
{
    public function pagination()
    {
        return function ($limit) {
            if (!is_null($limit)) {
                if ($limit === '0') {
                    return Builder::get();
                }

                return Builder::limit($limit)->get();
            }

            return Builder::paginate(config('constants.per_page'));
        };
    }
}
```

I use this method as a scope. I would suggest you watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8nz1JqbT9M